# assembly language help finding argv[1][0]

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, argv

I'm trying to get the first element of what is stored in `argv[1]` in x86 assembly language. 
I have popped the stack twice to `eax`  initially because I want `argc` so I can count the number of `argc`. Then popped `argv` to `ebx`. Im thinking of putting `[ebx]` into `bl`. From here I am lost. I have little or no experience in assembly, I am just looking to understand it.

```
main:
;
    mov ecx, 0 ;count output characters
    pop eax ;reject this 32 bits
    pop eax ;get argc
    ;
    pop ebx ; get argv
    ;mov bl, [ebx]
    ;
    add al, 30H ;convert integer to ascii
    mov edi, cline ;put char in output buffer
    mov byte [edi],al
    ;inc edi
    ;mov [edi], bl
    inc ecx ;increment output char count
    inc edi ;increment pointer to o/p buffer
    mov al, 0aH ;LF to end line
    mov byte[edi],al ;put it at end of output line
    inc ecx ;increment output char count
    push ecx ;save char count on stack
    mov edx,len ;length of string to write
    mov ecx,msg ;addr of string
    mov ebx,1 ;file descriptor 1 = stdout
    mov eax,4 ;"write" system call
    int 0x80 ;call the kernel
;
    pop edx ;restore char count into edx for system call
    mov ecx,cline ;address of string
    mov ebx,1 ;file descriptor 1 = stdout
```

Comment: Don't forget to use code blocks please. I fixed it for you.

Answer (score 7):

Take a look here: [NASM - Linux Getting command line parameters](https://web.archive.org/web/20200731195805/http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/285550-nasm-linux-getting-command-line-parameters/)

Here is how it works:

```
argc = [esp]
argv = [esp+4 + 4 * ARG_NUMBER]
```

Where ARG_NUMBER is the index into argv.  This is also equivalent to `[esp + 4*one_based_index]`, but that's harder to think about when you also have to remember that Unix `argv[0]` is the program name.

```
./test hello there
[esp] = 3
[esp+4 + 4 * 1] = ./test (program path and name)
[esp+4 + 4 * 2] = hello
[esp+4 + 4 * 3] = there
```

I will use printf from the C Library to make it clearer:

```
extern printf, exit

section .data
fmtint  db  "%d", 10, 0
fmtstr  db  "%s", 10, 0

section .text
global main
main:
    
    push    dword[esp]
    push    fmtint      
    call    printf                      ; print argc
    add     esp, 4 * 2

    mov     ebx, 1  
PrintArgV:
    push    dword [esp + 4 * ebx]
    push    fmtstr
    call    printf                      ; print each param in argv
    add     esp, 4 * 2
    
    inc     ebx
    cmp     ebx, dword [esp]
    jng     PrintArgV
    
    call    exit
```

There is no error checking here to keep it simple.  You could check to see if the number of args exceeds what you expect or whatever.

[image]

@Ed Cashin, if the OP is learning INTEL syntax, why confuse them with AT&T?

Comment: I'd suggest writing it as `[esp + 4  +  4 * ARG_INDEX]`, so you don't have to mess around with 1-based numbering.  Then everything matches up with C where`argv[1]` is the first arg after the program name.

Answer (score 0):

I have three recommendations:

1. Check out http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc9.html if you haven't already,
2. Minimize the code that attempts to solve your immediate problem, and
3. Examine the assembly generated by a C compiler if possible when you're stuck.

For getting argv, I can simply return the ASCII code for the first character in argv[1] from my program to avoid the system call.  The system call is a different problem than getting argv, so avoiding it focuses attention on the problem at hand.

Then I can compile a minimal C program and examine the generated assembly.  Reading AT&T syntax assembly isn't that bad if you remember that when you're going to AT&T, which is in New Jersey, the destination is on the right side of the U.S.  ;)

```
tmp$ cat main.c
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        if (argc > 1)
                return argv[1][0];
        return 0;
}
tmp$ gcc -Wall -save-temps main.c
```

The program just returns the ASCII code for the first character in argv[1].  The 't' is 116.

```
tmp$ ./a.out test
tmp$ echo $?
116
tmp$
```

Examining the generated assembly, I see that it doesn't use pops but rather just loads registers based on the position of stack parameters relative to the base pointer, ebp.  I find I like this style of using mov with the base pointer.

I don't use pop the way you're trying to do, so someone else might comment on how to do it using pop.

I've annotated the assembly a bit with comments about what I think is going on.  Corrections are welcome.

```
tmp$ cat main.s
        .file   "main.c"
        .text
.globl main
        .type   main,@function
main:
        pushl   %ebp         ; push the callers base pointer onto the stack
        movl    %esp, %ebp   ; save esp into the base pointer
        subl    $8, %esp     ; make some room on the stack for main ...
        andl    $-16, %esp   ; but pad to an aligned stack pointer
        movl    $0, %eax
        subl    %eax, %esp   ; dunno why gcc subtracts 0 from stack pointer
        cmpl    $1, 8(%ebp)  ; compare 1 and argc, which is 8 past the base pointer
        jle     .L2          ; jump to .L2 if argc <= 1
        movl    12(%ebp), %eax   ; fetch argv into eax
        addl    $4, %eax         ; skip the first 32 bits at that address
        movl    (%eax), %eax     ; fetch address from the resulting address
        movsbl  (%eax),%eax      ; load byte from that address into eax
        movl    %eax, -4(%ebp)   ; put that byte onto the stack (see note 1.)
        jmp     .L1
.L2:
        movl    $0, -4(%ebp)
.L1:
        movl    -4(%ebp), %eax   ; load return value from stack (see note 1.)
        leave
        ret
.Lfe1:
        .size   main,.Lfe1-main
        .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 3.2.2"
tmp$
```

I don't have nasm handy on a 32-bit machine, and x86_64 calling conventions are not the same as the ones you're dealing with, so I didn't translate this assembly into nasm syntax.

1. The compiler will do some stuff that makes you scratch your head and wonder, "Is that smart or dumb?"  In this case, I think probably I would just use eax itself instead of the stack for holding the return value, but sometimes googling is educational.  I learned why gcc sometimes likes to zero a register with "xor reg, reg", for example, by googling.

Comment: @Gunner asks why I used AT&T syntax when the OP is clearly using Intel syntax.  The reason is that I believe that achieving bilingual proficiency is less difficult than trying to avoid AT&T syntax altogether. The ability to check the output left by "-save-temps" makes up for any temporary confusion. To ease the discomfort further I provided a mnemonic.

Thanks for asking.

Comment: `gcc -Og -m32  -masm=intel -S` makes Intel syntax assembly so if you're trying to learn both syntaxes, you can see the same code both ways. See [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38552116).  If you want to compare against NASM, GAS Intel syntax is much closer, although it's MASM-like so NASM `mov reg, symbol` is GAS `mov reg, OFFSET symbol`.